# Transfer variable to template

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to transfer a variable to a template. I have tried:
${{ variables.portalPath }}
and
$(portalPath)

But no values are transferred. If I dont use a variable but just a string it works:

pipeline:

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
  - name: portalPath value:"sdfsdf"

extends:
  template: azure-pipelines-build-react-portal-template.yml
  parameters:
    portalPath: "I WOULD LIKE TO REPLACE THIS WITH VARIABLE"
```

Template:

```
parameters:
 - name: portalPath 
   type: string

steps:
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.portalPath }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run-time variables are not yet available at the time the value pass to `portalPath` is interpreted.  The template parameter would then receive a run-time variable $(portalPath).

Instead ofpassing the variable in *run-time syntax* but use the *expression syntax* `${{ variables.environment }}`:

#### Template.yml

```
parameters:

- name: portalPath # don't pass run-time variables

steps:
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.portalPath }}
```

#### azure-pipelines.yml

```
- stage: QA

  variables: 

    PortalPath : sdfsdf

  jobs:

  - template: azure-pipelines-build-react-portal-template.yml

    parameters:

      environment: ${{ variables.environment }} # use expression syntax
```

If this is still not work.  A workaround here is introducing simply a new variable in your in the beginning of your job (with powershell or bash):

`- powershell: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PortalPath ]${{ parameters.portalPath }}"`

From that point on you can use ${PortalPath }in your further steps.

You could also take a look at below similar question:

- [Azure Pipelines: Passing a variable as a parameter to a template](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/429990/azure-pipelines-passing-a-variable-as-a-parameter.html)
- [Passing variable as a parameter for conditions to template](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/986954/passing-variable-as-a-parameter-for-conditions-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

The example pipeline doesn't declare the variable value properly.

Not sure if this is just a typo when entering the question as the pipeline should fail upfront with your current variable declaration of:

```
variables:
  - name: portalPath value:"sdfsdf"
```

This template works for me:

```
variables:
  - name: portalPath
    value: "sdfsdf"

extends:
  template: my-template.yml
  parameters:
    portalPath: $(portalPath)
```

Comment: I just have value and name on one single line. Is that not allowed?

Comment: Came back with an error for me. I would have thought the YAML treats everything after the initial `p` as the value of name